# Zend framework - form not rendering

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, render

I'm just starting to use Zend Framework and was following the quick start documentation for the latest version (1.11.10). Everything was going just fine, but when I placed the form code and ran the application, the form did not render. My code is exactly like http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-form.html

On the view, I can dump the form just fine with `var_dump($this->form);`
I've tried `echo $this->form()`, `echo $this->form->render()`, but nothing appeared... What could it be?

Comment: post the source for your form, my guess is that if its var_dumping no problem that it should render unless something is messing up internally in the form.

Comment: here: http://pastebin.com/ceHyusFT

Comment: Post the form dump here.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can occur when Zend can't find the template file for an element. Look at following code:

```
 $element->setDecorators(array(
            array('ViewScript',
                array(
                    'viewScript' => 'directory/_input.phtml'
                )
            )
        ));
```

The file `_input.phtml` must be in the right folder for this Controller. Otherwise Zend can't find the template for  input and can't successfully render your element and will not show anything.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you pass the form to the view from the controller.

**In your action handler:**

```
$this->view->form = $my_form;
```

**In your view:**

```
echo $this->form;
```

I suspected that this was the cause of your problem because Zend Framework doesn't complain if you try to echo a parameter that doesn't exist. (i.e. `echo $this->some_fake_parameter` won't do anything)

Comment: no, that's not it. My controller is right: $form = new Application_Form_Guestbook(); $this->view->form = $form;

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i tried your code, and it worked for me no problem.
Here is everything:

Controller

```
<?php
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function myTestAction()
    {
        $form = new Form_Guestbook();

        // ... processing logics
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
    if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()))
    {
        var_dump($form->getValues());
    }
    }
        $this->view->assign('form', $form);
    }
}
```

Form

```
        <?php
        class Form_Guestbook extends Zend_Form
        {
            public function init()
            {
                // Set the method for the display form to POST
                $this->setMethod('post');

                // Add an email element
                $this->createElement('text', 'email', array(
                    'label'      => 'Your email address:',
                    'required'   => true,
                    'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
                    'validators' => array(
                        'EmailAddress',
                    )
                ));

                // Add the comment element
                $this->addElement('textarea', 'comment', array(
                    'label'      => 'Please Comment:',
                    'required'   => true,
                    'validators' => array(
                        array('validator' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array(0, 20))
                        )
                ));

                // Add a captcha
                $this->addElement('captcha', 'captcha', array(
                    'label'      => 'Please enter the 5 letters displayed below:',
                    'required'   => true,
                    'captcha'    => array(
                        'captcha' => 'Figlet',
                        'wordLen' => 5,
                        'timeout' => 300
                    )
                ));

                // Add the submit button
                $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
                    'ignore'   => true,
                    'label'    => 'Sign Guestbook',
                ));

                // And finally add some CSRF protection
                $this->addElement('hash', 'csrf', array(
                    'ignore' => true,
                ));
            }
        }
    ?>
```

View

```
<?php echo $this->form->render(); ?>
```

can be seen on: http://yaconiello.com/index/my-test

If this isnt working for you, you may be having a configuration error.

Comment: Weird... it's not working for me... Maybe it's my controller? here is the controller: http://pastebin.com/2gnYSQvN
It could be also a configuration error, but shouldn't it appear on apache's error log?

Comment: are you sure that you are echoing the $this->form->render in the view?

Comment: Absolutely. here's the code:

Please use the form below to sign our guestbook!
 
<?php
 $this->form->setAction($this->url());
 echo $this->form->render();
?>

I also tried with echo $this->form but it didn't work either

Comment: sorry, I'm running locally. I can zip the project and put it on a file sharing service if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like that (exact same form, since it is eclipse example) 
My problem was due to misunderstanding. Since I thought that I have to directly access to the view script. I entered in the browser something like: hostname/application/view/script/something.php

But in zend all accesses should be through public folder. You have to access to the view like this: hostname/app_name/public/guestbook

hope that would help you